# Sample input for various algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I have been reading parts of Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al, and have implemented some of the algorithms.

In order to test my implementations I wrote some glue code to do file io, then made some sample input by hand and some more sample input by writing programs that generate sample input.

However I am doubtful as to the quality of my own sample inputs -- corner cases; I may have missed the more interesting possibilities; I may have miscalculated the proper output; etc.

Is there a set of test inputs and outputs for various algorithms collected somewhere on the Internet so that I might be able to test my code? I am looking for test data reasonably specific to particular algorithms, rather than contest problems that often involve a problem solving component as well.

I understand that I might have to adjust my code depending on the format the input is collected in (e.g. The various constraints of the inputs; for graph algorithms, the representation of the graph; etc.) although, I am hoping that the change I would have to make would be reasonably trivial.

Edit:

Some particular datasets I am currently looking for are:

- Lists of numbers

  - Skewed so that Quick sort performs badly.
  - Skewed so that Fibonacci Heap performs particularly well or poorly for specific operations.
- Graphs (for which High Performance Mark has offered a number of interesting references)

  - Sparse graphs (with specific bounds on number of edges),
  - Dense graphs,

Since, I am still working through the book, if you are in a similar situation as I am, or you just feel  the list could be improved, please feel free to edit the list -- some time soon, I may come to need datasets similar to what you are looking for. I am not entirely sure how editing privileges work, but if I have any say over it, I will try to approve it.

Comment: what language are you using?  some languages have libraries that can automatically generate test data.  for example, quickcheck for haskell.  more are listed at http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3020132

Comment: @andrewcooke I am using Python. QuickCheck and such libraries sound interesting -- I will definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Another interesting testing tool is Korat (details at http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs295/papers/issta02.pdf), which actually inspects your code to construct exhaustive test cases for it on small inputs.  Again, not a collection of tests or in Python, but still a cool tool to know about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any one resource which will provide you with sample inputs for all the types of algorithm that Cormen *et al* cover but for graph datasets here are a couple of references:

[Knuth's Stanford Graphbase](http://www-cs-staff.stanford.edu/~uno/sgb.html)

and

the [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/)

which I stumbled across while looking for the link to the former.  You might be interested in this one too:

the [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/index.html)

Why not edit your question and let SO know what other types of input you are looking for.

Comment: I would add the Sparse Matrix collection. You can easily obtain a graph from a sparse matrix. http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/

Answer (score 0):

I am going to stick my head on the line and say that I do not know of any such source, and I very much doubt that such a source exists.

As you seem to be aware, algorithms can be applied to almost any sort of data, and so it would be fruitless to attempt to provide sample data.